# Not animating on left arrow key?

Tags: jquery

In the following code; when you press left arrow key the `#sprite` should be animated `left: 5%`; but is not doing anything. Please help; thanks! Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        #sprite {
            background-color:#0000ff;
            height:75px;
            width:75px;
            top:75%;
            left:50%;
            position:fixed;
            margin-left:-37px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.which == 37) {
                    $("#sprite").animate({ "left": "+=5%" }, "slow" );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div id="sprite"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: With your edit to fix the typo, you changed `13` to `37`. Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6xzND/

Comment: I did that to change it to left arrow key; also with enter it still does not work

Comment: Does my fiddle work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
$( "#spirte" )
```

Should be:

```
$( "#sprite" ).animate({ "left": "+=5%" }, "slow" );
```

Full Code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
console.log(event.which);
if (event.which == 37) 
{
    $("#sprite").animate({ "left": "+=5%" }, "slow" );
}
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/x3d5t/1/

Comment: Fixed it; still nothing

Comment: Thank you; it now works. Is it possible to make it so holding down the key repeats the function?

Comment: Actually, if you hold the left arrow it repeat the function :)